# php / mysql - how to get rankings of users?

Tags: php, mysql

for example i have a table like this :

```
name   rating
matei     124
andrei     20
serj       25
john      190
mike       96
andy      245
tom        73
```

i need to output something like this(order by rating):

john's position is 2; or, tom's position is 5; (i don't need to get all result , just one )

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question? If it's how to query the table, you may want to take a look at a basic PHP / mySQL tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) + 1
FROM    users
WHERE   (rating, name) <
        (
        SELECT  rating, name
        FROM    users
        WHERE   name = 'john'
        )
```

Note that if you will have duplicates on both name and rating, this query will assign the same rating to both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Generally order of rows in a query result is not guaranteed by MySQL unless ordering is explicitly specified with ORDER BY clause. If you have some separate ordering column, you may use query like the following:

```
SELECT count(1) as position
FROM table
WHERE order_column <= {john's order_column value};
```

If you don't have ordering column, I'd recommend you to define first, what does "john's position" and "tom's position" mean.

**UPDATE:**
AFAIU, you want to get position in list sorted by rating (sorry, I initially did not get it). So, rating would be your order_column. In this case, you should decide, how do you calculate position, if two guys have equal rating (who's position is higher?).

So, the query may look in the following way:

```
SELECT count(1) as position
FROM table
WHERE
    rating > (SELECT rating FROM table WHERE id={user's ID});
```

Comment: yes the rating is , i need to get the ranking of user order by rating

Comment: ok , thanks. hm...if two guys have equall rating... i don't know.. maybe order by name or something like this... but in this case what ways can i use?

Comment: I don't know :) That completely depends on what does position mean in your application. The simplest approach is: position = count(guys with higher rating) + 1. See query in answer by Quassnoi.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are more formally known as [relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29) in database literature - they are not guaranteed to be ordered (they are sets of "tuples"), so your question doesn't make sense.  If you need to rely on an order/position, you need to define an additional column (like an auto-incrementing ID column) to capture and store that info.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any help > http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Would offset not work like so?

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 1,6
```

This would return 1 row that has been off setted by 6 rows ? or am I mistaken, the syntax would be

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 1 , {{POS}}
```

Comment: look , yes i need to order by rating users but i need to receive just the ranking of specific user not of all users, for exaple ( john's ranking is 2 );